# What is the correct chemical formula for monosodium glutamate?

Tags: notation

Recently, I am interested with home materials and I discover that the chemical symbol for MSG or monosodium glutamate is $\ce{C5H8NO4Na}$.
My problem is shouldn't it be $\ce{NaC5H8NO4}$ as we always write the metal first before the non-metal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should, but in organic molecules salts, often the counterion is written latter, to indicate its position on the molecule acting like so, for example, in sodium acetate, $\ce{CH3CO2Na}$, this would be something like a "semicondensated" formula.

Comment: Agreed. Usually the organic (carbon containing) part of the molecule is written in the [Hill notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_system) and the counter ion added to the end. Usually this is done, because it makes ordering in a Database easier. Note that the correct Hill formula for MSG would be $\ce{C5H8NNaO4}$. Compare to [Sigma-Aldrich Data Sheet](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma/Product_Information_Sheet/g1626pis.pdf)